# How do I add "Parent Reference item" to "File item List" using C#

Tags: c#, reference, parent

I'm trying to fetch Google Drive items & adding my own item dynamically for temporary use.

```
IList<File> Files = new List<File>();
FilesResource.ListRequest list = service.Files.List();
FileList filesFeed = list.Execute();

ParentReference pitem = new ParentReference();

File fileitem = new File();
fileitem.Id = RootId;
fileitem.Title = "MainDrive";
pitem.Id = null;
pitem.IsRoot = true;

fileitem.Parents.Add(pitem);

Files.Add(fileitem);
```

In the above code I'm able to add Google Drive file items plus my own `fileitem` to `Files` List.

To fetch the parent id I have to write the below code

```
(x => x.Files[0].Parent[0].Id)
```

But for the item which I added has `fileitem.Parents` itself is null, then how can I add parent id equal null(pitem.Id = null;)?? Throwing exception.

When i'm trying to add parent reference to List, It's throwing the error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Can you please post the code where you call that anonymous function?

Comment: IList<File> _Files = GoogleDriveHelper.GetFiles(reusableservice, null); Where GoogleDriveHelper is a class file.the above function is belongs to here....Thank you,any how i got the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I got it...
fileitem.Parents = new List() { new ParentReference() { Id = _parent } };

from the below link:
http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/[^]

Thank you soo much Ms.Linda ;-)